# I want to search for a method inside a java class. I have method name as String and name of the class in which I am looking into

Tags: java, methods, reflection

```
class A {
    method x() {
    }

    method y() {
    }
}

class B {
    A a = new A();
    String methodName = "x";
    // I want to execute this statement **a.x();**
}
```

I know the method name and I want to call the method automatically.

Comment: what are you expecting us to understand from this ?? explain please

Answer (score 0):

In your case just call:

```
a.getClass().getMethod(methodName, null).invoke(a);
```

Remember about thrown exceptions:

```
NoSuchMethodException
InvocationTargetException
IllegalAccessException
```

And make `x` method public or just use `getDeclaredMethod` instead of `getMethod`.